# How do I switch from python 2.6 to 2.7 by default

Tags: python, python-2.7, centos, pip, redhat

How do I switch from python 2.6 to 2.7 by default

```
ls -l /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Jan 27 12:36 /usr/bin/python -> python2.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Jan 27 12:36 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.6
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 3664 Sep 13 00:25 /usr/bin/python26
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 3664 Sep 13 00:25 /usr/bin/python2.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1418 Sep 13 00:25 /usr/bin/python2.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 3664 Nov 12 02:03 /usr/bin/python27
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 3664 Nov 12 02:03 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 Sep  1 09:52 /usr/bin/python3 -> /usr/local/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Jan 27 12:36 /usr/bin/python-config -> python2.6-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Jan 27 12:36 /usr/bin/python-config2 -> python2.6-config
```

Answer (score 2):

A lot of Ubuntu packages use python. They also install modules in `/usr/lib/pythonX.Y` where (`X.Y` is your default python version).

The python packaging system only provides those modules for the default python.

If you change your default python, it would become *your responsibility* to provide those modules for the new version of python *or else your system will break*.

Therefore, unless you really know what you are doing (i.e. you are willing to port and maintain all those modules), I would strongly recommend not trying to change the default version of python.

Instead use [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) and [`virtualenvwrapper`](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to allow you to switch versions at the user level.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder in your home folder like .bin (or whatever you want)

Open your terminal configuration file (.bashrc , .zshrc ..) and modify your $PATH variable. like

```
export PATH=$HOME/.bin:$PATH
```

then put a symlink to there.

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 ~/.bin/python
ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7-config ~/.bin/python-config
```

with this way you don't have to change something systemwide.

otherwise you can change the global symlinks to change them system wide. But i can affect sth. you don't know.

The first method will be more stable & secure.