# Yum not working after update

Tags: python, python-2.7, sudo, yum

How do I resolve this error. Can anyone help to find this?

```
sudo yum groupinstall -y 'development tools'
```

Got following error:

```
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   /usr/lib/librpm.so.3: undefined symbol: selinux_status_close

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.9 (unknown, Sep 13 2014, 00:25:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

Comment: I think this is because you're using an old version of python. Install a newer version of Python, and then run.

Comment: @Games Brainiac Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171007/how-do-i-switch-from-python-2-6-to-2-7-by-default